# How to print the smallest number from a set of inputted integer?

Tags: c, helper

I want to write a program where it prompts people to enter a set of integers separated by a space. The user should be able to enter any amount of integer. It will find the two smallest integer in the set and print it out. Printing the smallest number and then printing the second smallest. My question is how do I get the value of min1 to be the first integer they enter, other than a static one? When I did a test run all it printed was a space, why is that? Here is what I have so far:

Update:
I'm now trying this approach, but it just freeze after I enter an input such as 76 5 74 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int min1, min2;
int input;

int main(){

  printf("Please enter some integer: ");
  scanf("%d", &min1);
  while(scanf("%d", &input) != 0){
      min1=input;
    }
  printf("%d", min1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes because it didn't contain a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `\n` in the end of the first printf, so it will not buffered.

Also, be care that you work with digits - not integers.

and for your question - just write `min1=getchar();`.

EDIT: some code that may do what that you want:

```
printf("Enter numbers. (other chars to end)\n");
int min,input;
scanf("%d",&min);
while (scanf("%d",&input))
 if (input<min)
  min=input;
printf("min: %d\n",min);
```

Comment: Wouldn't getchar() get just one character? What id it is a 2 character integer?

Comment: This has helped so far. I got it to output the smallest. Now I'm working on making it output the second smallest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need `scanf("%d", &number);` to read integers.
For your question, just call `scanf` to read the first number, or set up a flag to indicate if it's the first input.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you got a space printed? Because %c prints characters not numbers, try %d.

But even after that you won't get the answer you are looking for. `getchar()` gets a character (go figure...) from the user input, and you are storing that character into a numeric value, for single digit numbers it would magically work since even as characters '9' > '8' > '7' > ... > '0', but you'll get the ascii value of the smallest number printed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

1. Some way for the user to tell your program they are done entering numbers, so some kind of conditional statement
2. Some way to compare the numbers they have entered so another conditional statement comparing numbers

In sudocode, maybe something like:

```
while (user still wants to give numbers):
    number = get user input
    if number does not equal exit_case:
        if number < current minimum number:
            current minimum number = number
    else:
        break out of the while loop
print current minimum number
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
int a,b=1,min;

printf("Enter Number\n");
scanf("%d",&min);

while(b<10)
{
scanf("%d",&a);
if(min>a)
{
min=a;
}
b++;
}
printf("Smallest Num ::%d",min);
}
```

Comment: You should explain why this answers the question.